# Why do all my photos look blurry on my Nikon D3300?

Tags: nikon-d3300

When I take photos on my Nikon D3300, unless it's in auto mode, the photos are always incredibly bad quality and too dark, even though the ISO is on the highest. What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it? This only happens when I take photos, videos are perfectly fine [image]

Comment: In full manual control you can easily under or overexpose your pictures. You can try aperture priority first, in that mode you set the aperture and the  camera will itself determine the exposure (which you can override but the default will yield a reasonably good exposure).

Comment: "incredibly bad" it is not helpful for anyone, including you. If you want to learn, you need to identify and categorize. Post sample images, not "incredibly bad", but with specific issues you identified. That way you can correct them.

Comment: Rafael I've added a picture

Comment: The more information, the better... What are your settings for aperture and exposure? What lens are you using? What program mode (the letter or symbol on the top dial)?

Comment: Also does this happen if you shoot outdoors in the sunshine? What lens are you using? Are you using a tripod or flash? In the meantime, you may also want to see: [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/) and [What is noise in a digital photograph?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11910/) and [What is the "exposure triangle"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle)

Comment: what settings are you using? Maybe your speed/time is set to 'very short', like 1/4000, and nothing else you change will save you from the consequences.

Comment: "Unless it's in auto mode": If you have taken it out of auto mode, you need to understand what is no longer being done automatically for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my photos not crisp?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp)

Answer (score 1):

"Incredibly bad" might be because you are using too high ISO. Use Manual Mode, open up the aperture to the widest, set the shutter speed to 1/100 and then adjust the ISO as necessary. And use the viewfinder while taking stills. Quality of the photos taken in LV is not WYSIWG (not at least with D5100, which I use).

Answer (score 1):

The more the higher ISO, more will be the noise in image. Always, try keeping the ISO at minimum level as possible. Use wide aperture and shutter speed of suitable speed to capture photos. If you are new to photography, don't directly jump into manual mode. Try aperture, shutter priority mode first. As a first, learn the triangle of photography: aperture, shutter and ISO and keep experimenting with them. Good Luck!